# Find all indices with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a program that finds all of the index values for specific element in list or a string. I *have to* use recursion, and my function can only take two arguments.

My problem is that my program finds only the first index and then stop. How can I change it to meet my requirements?

My code:

```
def find_all(L, v):
    return 0 if L[0] == v else 1 + find_all(L[1:], v)
```

Input:

1. `find_all( [1,2,3,4,2,4,5,2,1], 2)`
2. `find_all("hello wonderful world", "w")`

Desired output:

1. `[1,4,7]`
2. `[6,16]`

Comment: I think you are making it harder on yourself by trying to write a one-liner. Try instead breaking any recursive problem down as:

    `def find_all(L, v):
      if condition :
        return base_cases;
      else :
        recursive_calls;`

Comment: Are you tring to re-implement `findall` from [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) ?

Comment: don't see any reason to use recursion: `return [i[0] for i in enumerate(L) if i[1] == v]`

Comment: If you want lists for your output, then you need to create a list at some point to hold your accumulated results

Comment: @lenik. this is the question, I have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pythons ability to walk backwards through a list and grab the last element.  Then put lists together with the + operator. By going through the list backwards you're able to find the indice when a value is found, rather than losing it when you move from the start of the list to the end.

```
def find_all(L, v):
    if not L:
            return []

    result = []
    if L[-1] == v:
            result = [len(L)-1]

    return find_all(L[:-1], v) + result
```

Comment: what is the term 'if not L' means?

Comment: You should look this up as that's part of the homework. It just means "If L is empty, then stop our recursion"

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of a counter somehow. The idea is to use `find_all(L, v)` as an interface to the "real" recursive function :

```
def find_all(L, v):
    return _find_all(L, v, 0)

def _find_all(L, v, position):
    # Your algorithm here
```

Considering this is homework, I will not do the work for you but you should be able to keep going from here.

Answer (score 0):

Code in C++

```
 int allIndexes(int input[], int size, int x, int output[]){

 if(size==0)
      return 0;
    int ans=allIndexes(input, size-1, x , output );
    if(input[size-1]==x)
    {
        output[ans]=size-1;
       return ans+1; 
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: This question clearly shows that the code is in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
int AllIndexesRecursive(int input[], int size, 
                    int x, int output[]) 
{ 

    // If an empty array comes 
    // to the function, then 
    // return zero 
    if (size == 0) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    // Getting the recursive answer 
    int smallAns = AllIndexesRecursive(input + 1, 
                                    size - 1, x, output); 

    // If the element at index 0 is equal 
    // to x then add 1 to the array values 
    // and shift them right by 1 step 
    if (input[0] == x) { 
        for (int i = smallAns - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            output[i + 1] = output[i] + 1; 
        } 

        // Put the start index in front 
        // of the array 
        output[0] = 0; 
        smallAns++; 
    } 
    else { 

        // If the element at index 0 is not equal 
        // to x then add 1 to the array values 
        for (int i = smallAns - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            output[i] = output[i] + 1; 
        } 
    } 
    return smallAns; 
} 

// Function to find all indices of a number 
void AllIndexes(int input[], int n, int x) 
{ 
    int output[n]; 
    int size = AllIndexesRecursive(input, n, 
                                x, output); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        cout << output[i] << " "; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Java code:
/ Java program to find all 
// indices of a number 
public class GFG { 
  
    public int[] AllIndexesRecursive(int input[], 
                                int x, int start) 
    { 
        // If the start index reaches the 
        // length of the array, then 
        // return empty array 
        if (start == input.length) { 
            int[] ans = new int[0]; // empty array 
            return ans; 
        } 
  
        // Getting the recursive answer in 
        // smallIndex array 
        int[] smallIndex = AllIndexesRecursive(input, x, 
                                              start + 1); 
  
        // If the element at start index is equal 
        // to x then 
        // (which is the answer of recursion) and then 
        // (which came through recursion) 
        if (input[start] == x) { 
            int[] myAns = new int[smallIndex.length + 1]; 
  
            // Put the start index in front 
            // of the array 
            myAns[0] = start; 
            for (int i = 0; i < smallIndex.length; i++) { 
                  
                // Shift the elements of the array 
                // one step to the right 
                // and putting them in 
                // myAns array 
                myAns[i + 1] = smallIndex[i]; 
            } 
            return myAns; 
        } 
        else { 
              
            // If the element at start index is not 
            // equal to x then just simply return the 
            // answer which came from recursion. 
            return smallIndex; 
        } 
    }
```